# Django: Writing Generic View Options

Tags: django, django-views, django-generic-views

I have a Django view that I would like to reuse rather than copy and paste that loads and validates before executing some custom logic.

I'm evaluating three methods to make this view reusable:

1. Decorator (Not Djangoish)
2. Generic View Method (Investigating)
3. Class Based Generic View (A bit of an overkill)

What would you recommend and why?

I've provided a snippet of the view below:

```
try:
    data = json.loads(request.body)
except:
    resp = generate_json_response(False, 'validation', 'JSON data cannot be parsed. Please check your data format.')
    return HttpResponse(resp, mimetype="application/json")

# Validation
location = data.get('location', None)
if location:
    {custom logic}

else: 
    # No Location
    resp = generate_json_response(False, 'validation', 'Missing location id')
    return HttpResponse(resp, mimetype="application/json")

resp = generate_json_response(True, None, None)
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp), mimetype="application/json")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you think about to use Class Based Generic View with mixins?
Something like that:

```
class JSONResponseMixin(object):
    def render_to_response(self, context):
        return self.get_json_response(json.dumps(context))

    def get_json_response(self, content, **httpresponse_kwargs):
        return http.HttpResponse(content,
                   content_type='application/json',
                   **httpresponse_kwargs)


class MyView(JSONResponseMixin, SomeView(BaseDetail, BaseUpdate etc..)):
    pass
```

Maybe it would be better to use some json-rpc implementation for your purposes. Take a look:

http://json-rpc.org/

http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC#Implementations